# document.getElementById is not getting the input

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get what's inside an input through `document.getElementById`, it does get other values but specifically for this one it does not.

`let title_input = document.getElementById('HomeworkTitle').value;` that's what I'm trying to do, to then use it here:

```
function saveHomework() {

        let title_input = document.getElementById('HomeworkTitle').value;
        let image_input = document.getElementById('image').value;
        let progress_input = document.getElementById('progress').value;
        let description_input = document.getElementById('description').value;
        let duedate_input = document.getElementById('duedate').value;

        axios.post('/storeHomework', {

            subject_id: {{ $id->id }},
            title: title_input,
            image: image_input,
            progress: progress_input,
            description: description_input,
            duedate: duedate_input

        }).then((response) => {

            console.log(response)
            $("#exampleModal .close").click();

        }).catch((error) => {

            console.log(error.response.data)

        });
        $('#thisdiv').load(document.URL +  ' #thisdiv');
    }

    saveHomework();
```

In the HTML I got:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="HomeworkTitle" id="HomeworkTitle" class="form-control" aria-describedby="help">
                <small id="help" class="form-text text-muted">Ex: Investigate blah blah blah.</small>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Description:</label>
                <textarea type="text" name="description" id="description" class="form-control" aria-describedby="help"></textarea>
                <small id="help" class="form-text text-muted">Point out here details about the homework (optional).</small>
            </div> 

            <div class="input-group mb-3 px-2 py-2 rounded-pill bg-white shadow-sm">
                <input id="image" type="file" name="image" onchange="readURL(this);" class="form-control border-0">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <label for="upload" class="btn btn-light m-0 rounded-pill px-4"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload mr-2 text-muted"></i><small class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-muted">Choose file</small></label>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Deadline:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="date" id="duedate" name="duedate">
            </div> 

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Current progress:</label>
                <div class="range-slider">
                    <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" step="10" id="progress" name="progress">
                    <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
                </div>
            </div> 
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" onclick="saveHomework()">Add Homework</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Not sure why it's not working.

Comment: There is no problem in this code you shared. it gives result. So problem is different. Can u crreate snipped?

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: We need to see more code to understand problem. There is no error in your sharings. Where u create title_input. When u get it, is there any second element whose id is HomeworkTitle?

Comment: Okay, let me update.

Comment: updated @pc_coder

Comment: are you triggering saveHomework() with a button I assume because that function is almost inmediatly invoked.

Comment: Why are u calling function before enter anything u need button to click and call function

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add that part. It's not what you think.

Comment: @pc_coder edited... again.

Comment: It still gives result https://jsfiddle.net/0mpzqgus/1/ @Daniel Logvin Problem is not here. Do u use form element in modal ? If yes u need to take your submit button into form, Or u can try to change type submit to button

Comment: @pc_coder I found the solution. This was a problem in the backend, not in the front-end. I appreciate the help though! Mind if we call a "close" for a typo?

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure your javascript file is properly linked
try this

```
document.getElementById("HomeworkTitle").value;
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if single or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```js
  var title_input = ''
        let check = document.getElementById("HomeworkTitle")
        check.addEventListener("focusout", myFunction);

        function myFunction() {
        title_input = check.value
          console.log(check.value)
        }
    /////////////here you can you variable//////////////////
    //axios.post('/storeHomework', {
    //console.log('title_input',title_input)
                //title: title_input, //here
       // }

function saveHomework() {
        let image_input = document.getElementById('image').value;
        let progress_input = document.getElementById('progress').value;
        let description_input = document.getElementById('description').value;
        let duedate_input = document.getElementById('duedate').value;

        axios.post('/storeHomework', {

            subject_id: {{ $id->id }},
            title: title_input,
            image: image_input,
            progress: progress_input,
            description: description_input,
            duedate: duedate_input

        }).then((response) => {

            console.log(response)
            $("#exampleModal .close").click();

        }).catch((error) => {

            console.log(error.response.data)

        });
        $('#thisdiv').load(document.URL +  ' #thisdiv');
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="HomeworkTitle" id="HomeworkTitle" class="form-control" aria-describedby="help">
                <small id="help" class="form-text text-muted">Ex: Investigate blah blah blah.</small>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Description:</label>
                <textarea type="text" name="description" id="description" class="form-control" aria-describedby="help"></textarea>
                <small id="help" class="form-text text-muted">Point out here details about the homework (optional).</small>
            </div> 

            <div class="input-group mb-3 px-2 py-2 rounded-pill bg-white shadow-sm">
                <input id="image" type="file" name="image" onchange="readURL(this);" class="form-control border-0">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <label for="upload" class="btn btn-light m-0 rounded-pill px-4"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload mr-2 text-muted"></i><small class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-muted">Choose file</small></label>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Deadline:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="date" id="duedate" name="duedate">
            </div> 

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Current progress:</label>
                <div class="range-slider">
                    <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" step="10" id="progress" name="progress">
                    <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
                </div>
            </div> 
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" onclick="saveHomework()">Add Homework</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not using react.

Comment: No problem you can use listener like this and create one global variable after put input you can update your variable and use

Answer (score -1):

what error are you getting? maybe your input is empty and that´s why you don´t gent anything?

```js
function saveHomework() {
    const title = document.getElementById("HomeworkTitle");
    console.log(title.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="HomeworkTitle" value="somevalue">
<button onclick="javascript:saveHomework()">save</button>
```

Comment: How is my input empty if I'm the one adding a title to it...?

Comment: do you have like a submit button that calls axios?

Comment: Yes, it executes `onclick="saveHomework()"` I stated before that it does retrieve other inputs but this one specifically does not.

Comment: see my updated answer. I added a save button and a save function and it returns the updated value properly